# Gimp image editor isn't starting at all

Tags: gimp

I've installed gimp image editor on my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64-bit.

If I start it from the terminal it only says:

> Segmentation fault (core dumped)

I've already tried to uninstall and reinstall it again like this:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge gimp
sudo apt-get remove gimp
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get install gimp
gimp
```

As instructed I tried `dpkg -l gimp`, then I get:

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold 
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend 
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad) 
||/ Name    Version      Architecture Description
+++-==============-============-============-=================================
ii  gimp           2.8.10-0ubun amd64        The GNU Image Manipulation Progra
```

Comment: How did you install Gimp?

Comment: Can you include the output of `dpkg -l gimp` and update your original question to include this? Thanks

Comment: Try the following command: `mv -v $HOME/.gimp-2.8/  $HOME/.gimp-2.8_bak` and then restart gimp.